# How to stop function printing None

Tags: python, printing

[I created a moral machine similar to the trolley problem. Here I have the simulation function that reads into a csv and calls two other functions that determine the priority of the subject. It calls and prints everything just fine but it prints None in between the score and details for every line read. How do I just print the score and information without that?[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmjRO.jpg) [][function]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgBDB.jpg)

Comment: Hello you should add your code as codeblock not as image.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the name `printPersonDetails` – it seems like this function itself prints the details of the person, but does not return a value itself.
This means the `details` variable is set to `None` (the return value of `printPersonDetails`) and is then printed on the next line.

Try removing the line `print(details)` as this, I presume, is what is printing "None" to the terminal.